I need a datasheet for an 8-pin IC marked as N 2800 311
I'm trying to identify this integrated circuit that is on a small PCB to control a photodiode. I think it's from an old TV. I imagine it's used to increase the voltage of the photodiode but I'm not sure.
My intentions would be to reuse it with another project (the whole board) but since I don't know which pin is Vcc I haven't tried it yet.
The PCB came inside a metal casing with a label inscription MN2 372 and a faint laser inscription on the metal OTERN.

In the following images you can see a poor attempt at a schematic and photos of the circuit and the integrated circuit. I did not find the data sheet for the 8-pin IC and I do not know what it does either, it has the inscription N 2800 311 (I think it is from National Semiconductor). The values ​​of the capacitors and the SMD resistor were measured outside the circuit. The 35k and 50 ohm resistors are internal resistances of the integrated circuit.



Are the capacitors attached to pins 6 and 7 actually multiple millifarads? That's very hard to believe.

The two capacitors on pins 6 and 7 are ceramic and the values ​​written on paper are in nanofarads (nF). They were measured by an auto-ranging multimeter and it gave those two values. I think one of the capacitors is very degraded but I don't know if the 1.66nF is a correct value.

It sure looks like you wrote "mF" there. nF makes more sense, though.

It's a Renesas (formerly NEC) μPC2800A remote control pre-amplifier.


(Source: 1688.com)

Thanks for the datasheet, I couldn't find it anywhere! It has the same circuit as the application. Regards.

I would guess module P2 is Vcc and P3 is ground, and the output is P1. You could try putting 100Ω in series and increasing the voltage slowly from 0V to see what current it draws (probably 1mA or less).
But it's hardly worth bothering, modern versions of these devices (which have a ~38kHz (depending on type) demodulator as well as an amplifier and a photodiode) are available for well under a dollar. Digikey has some obsolete (but with datasheet) ones for 29 cents in single quantity. Current production ones such as these are still inexpensive. The overall performance is specified and guaranteed, including the photodiode.

If that will break the bank, LCSC has these for around 10 cents in singles.
Note that these are not general-purpose IR devices- they are designed to demodulate IR remote controls with a specific carrier frequency, often, but not always, around 38kHz. They are intended to receive bursts of light close to that specific frequency.

Thanks for the information, I will continue investigating to see if I can use it for my project, I have never experimented with IR signals. Regards.
